# Android Threads waiting

Tags: java, android, multithreading, thread-safety, android-asynctask

in my Android app I use a initial Activity for making a loading splash with an ASyncTask and then launch the mainactivity which downloads about 10 images and shows it to the user in a table.
I just started today to investigate the DDMS and the debug mode and I see that after the app load, I have one thread for the asynctask and 10 http threads waiting. Is that normal? Shouldn't they die with the last instruction executed?

Here is my code:

```
public void download (String imageURL, String path, String filename){
     new Thread(){
       public void run() {
                    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                try {
                    //Create the path
                    new File(path).mkdirs();
                    //File to download
                    File file = new File(path+filename);
                    if (!file.exists()){
                        Log.d(Manager.getAppName(),file.getName()+" dont exists");
                        URL url = new URL(imageURL);
                        URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();
                        InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
                        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
                        ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(50);
                        int current = 0;
                        while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
                                baf.append((byte) current);
                        }
                        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        fos.write(baf.toByteArray());
                        bis.close();
                        fos.close();
                                    is.close();
                        Log.d(Manager.getAppName(), "download ready in "
                                        +( (float)(System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 1000f)
                                        + " sec");
                    } else {
                        Log.d(Manager.getAppName(),"File exists (ignoring)");

                    }
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (latch!=null){
                    latch.countDown();
                    Log.d(Manager.getAppName(),"Download finished "+latch.getCount()+" remaining");
                }
            }
        }).start();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Threads will not die if they are part of a Thread Pool. Are you starting them yourself?

Comment: Please provide code that you use to start them and relevant parts from `run()`. Update the question, please.

Comment: Yes Im curious about this topic, please update the question with your code.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct behavior as AsyncTask and libraries like okhttp use thread pool. Depending on the system, there will be a max number of threads that can be in the pool. Whenever a new thread is needed (like when a new AsyncTask is created), one of the idling threads from the pool will be used thereby preventing the overhead involved in creating a new thread every time. Once the task finishes, the thread returns to the idle state in the pool with status "wait".